# AuthenticationSuccessHandler alerts no qualifying bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I got some problem when trying to use spring security 4.2.3 with the AuthenticationSuccessHandler while it alerts:

> Error creating bean with name 'customWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
>   'customAuthenticationSuccesshandler'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.test.smsportal.common.filter.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler'.

The strange thing is that I already declared @Component for the success handler.

below is my CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler:

```
package com.test.smsportal.common.filter;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ADMIN")) {
            response.sendRedirect("admin/home.html");
        } else if (roles.contains("USER")) {
            response.sendRedirect("static/user.html");
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
package com.test.smsportal.configuration;

import com.test.smsportal.common.filter.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccesshandler;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user") // #1
                .password("password").roles("USER").and().withUser("admin") // #2
                .password("password").roles("ADMIN", "USER");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/public/**"); // #3
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/signup", "/about").permitAll() // #4
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")// #6
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // 7
                .and().formLogin() // #8
                .loginPage("/login") // #9
                .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccesshandler); // #5
                //.permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/static/user.html");
    }
}
```

Below is my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
package com.sgx.smsportal.configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.smsportal.controller", 
"com.test.smsportal.service", "com.test.smsportal.dao",
    "com.test.smsportal.common.filter" })
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 //something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `@ComponentScan` in `MvcConfiguration` doesn't cover package `com.test.smsportal.configuration` and CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter also doesn't include a `@ComponentScan` covering `com.test.smsportal.common.filter`.

You can either do

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.smsportal.controller", 
"com.test.smsportal.service", "com.test.smsportal.dao",
    "com.test.smsportal.common.filter", "com.test.smsportal.configuration"})
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 //something
}
```

or

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.smsportal.controller", 
"com.test.smsportal.service", "com.test.smsportal.dao",
    "com.test.smsportal.common.filter"})
@Import({CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class})
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 //something
}
```

or

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.smsportal.common.filter" })
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

}
```